# VLC stream to MP4 WEBM and Flash

Tags: video-streaming, mp4, vlc, http-live-streaming, webm

I am trying to stream video from a IP Cam to my my Wordpress site. I would like my stream to be available via common devices Windows, Mac, Android and IOS. Currently I am using VLC to stream,but I can only get a flash stream to work but I would like to do FLV, MP4 and webm. What player should I use to display the MP4 and webm video on the site? Also I don't think the calls to VLC are correct cause I can't open the MP4 and webm stream in VLC on another computer, but I can open the flv stream.

VLC Script:

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC"

vlc -vvv -I dummy http://IP/cgi/mjpg/mjpg.cgi :sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=200,deinterlace,ab=32,fps=25,width=460,height=480}:duplicate{dst=std{access=http{mime=video/x-flv},dst=0.0.0.0:8080/webcam.flv}}
vlc -vvv -I dummy http://IP/cgi/mjpg/mjpg.cgi :sout=#transcode{vcodec=VP80,vb=200,deinterlace,ab=32,fps=25,width=460,height=480,acodec=vorb}:duplicate{dst=std{access=http{mime=video/x-webm},dst=0.0.0.0:8080/webcam.webm}}
vlc -vvv -I dummy http://IP/cgi/mjpg/mjpg.cgi :sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=200,deinterlace,ab=32,fps=25,width=460,height=480}:duplicate{dst=std{access=http{mime=video/x-mp4},dst=0.0.0.0:8080/webcam.mp4}}
```

FLV Player Code:

```
<object id="player1" width="640" height="480" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0">
    <param name="flashvars" value="file=http://VLC_IP:8080/webcam.flv&amp;autostart=true&stretching=exactfit" />
    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
    <param name="src" value="http://player.longtailvideo.com/player.swf" />
    <embed id="player1" width="640" height="480" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="http://player.longtailvideo.com/player.swf" flashvars="file=http://VLC_IP:8080/webcam.flv&amp;autostart=true&stretching=exactfit" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" />
</object>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stream **WebM** you can use the following command (worked on arch linux setup)

```
cvlc \
$source \
--sout '#transcode{vcodec=VP80,vb=2000,scale=0,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:std{access=http{mime=video/webm},mux=webm,dst=:8080/cam1}' \
-vvv
```

Although this (webm) is not officially supported. See these supported formats [matrices](http://www.videolan.org/streaming-features.html)

For the documentation of sout params please see the [official page](http://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/ch03.html#id345440)

As for **MP4**:

It is not supported at all

Comment: what was your html code ? mine says "no video with supported mime type found"