# Raspberry Pi RTSP steam in browser

Tags: html, video-streaming, raspberry-pi, vlc, rtsp

I have set up a RTSP stream from my raspberry pi camera module using this:

```
raspivid -o - -t 9999999 |cvlc -vvv stream:///dev/stdin --sout '#rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/}' :demux=h264
```

I am able to view it using VLC with: `rtsp://192.168.0.18:8554/`

When I attempt to embed the video in a web page the video does not show.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><body>
<OBJECT classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921"
 codebase="http://downloads.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/latest/win32/axvlc.cab"
 width="800" height="600" id="vlc" events="True">
 <param name="Src" value="rtsp://192.168.0.18:8554/" />
 <param name="ShowDisplay" value="True" />
 <param name="AutoLoop" value="False" />
 <param name="AutoPlay" value="True" />
 <embed id="vlcEmb" type="application/x-google-vlc-plugin" version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2" autoplay="yes" loop="no" width="640" height="480"
 target="rtsp://192.168.0.18:8554/" ></embed>
</OBJECT>
</body></html>
```

What is the best way to embed the video feed in HTML to view it in a web browser?

Answer (score 0):

Well this is a bit tricky - when you open the RTSP link directly with VLC it should work since VLC comes packed with all the codecs (in your case H264). However I'm not aware of what happens with the browser plugin - does it reuse the codecs from the VLC installation or what. It could be that a codec is simply missing on the viewer's end but I'm not sure about that. Also, using the plugin you could run into issues with support among different browsers and whatnot.

The html5 video thing is a bit sketchy since as far as I remember (and this may have changed) neither live H.264 nor WebM is fully supported across all browsers. I'd still go with WebM since Chrome and Firefox has it and only IE requires an add-on. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18088222/vlc-stream-to-mp4-webm-and-flash) question, it has a valid WebM streaming command line in the response and see if that works for you. If it does you should be even able to omit all the `embed` stuff and just use a plain HTML5 video tag.